# jQuery and OpenSocial (particularly Orkut)

Tags: jquery, opensocial

I want to develop a webpage which fetches some data from my Orkut account using [OpenSocial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSocial) APIs. The language I am working with is JavaScript and I use jQuery. However I must admit that I am a novice as far as JavaScript is concerned.

I have looked at [OpenSocial jQuery](http://code.google.com/p/opensocial-jquery/). It seems restricted to gadgets and jOpenSocial lacks any good documentation and does not seem to be handling [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth). Can you suggest a JavaScript library which is easy to use as a wrapper around OpenSocial?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like opensocial-jquery will satisfy most of what you need.  It's not limited to gadgets (here's a fetch person example: http://code.google.com/p/opensocial-jquery/wiki/ExamplePerson) and it wraps gadgets.io.makeRequest, which allows the AJAX functions to work.

I'm not sure what you mean by "handling OAuth" - you shouldn't need to do much in the way of implementing OAuth.  There is a feature called the OAuth proxy in iGoogle, but opensocial-jquery supports that as well: http://code.google.com/p/opensocial-jquery/wiki/ExampleFriendFeedOAuth (appears to be in Japanese but the sample code is easy enough to understand).